# iText library in Java vs Puppeteer in Node For Pdf Generation from HTML

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, puppeteer

I want to generate pdf out of html page and create service for the same in either Node.js or Java. Which one is better feature and performance wise, iText or Puppeteer?

Also do selenium provides pdf generation feature same as Puppeteer in Node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you define "features" and "performance". I'm not sure which converter is *faster*, but there's a dramactic difference between their conversion abilities.

Puppeteer is based on Google Chromium and will have the most up-to-date support for CSS functionality such as Flexbox and Grid. It also supports JavaScript, which is nice for creating charts or generation tables of content.

On the other hand, iText is more customizable and powerful. iText can create a more advanced PDF than Puppeteer. It supports accessible PDFs and PDF forms, for example.

Yes, Selenium can also create PDFs.